# Set Custom Button View to BackBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface, uinavigationbar

I am trying to change all back buttons to following:

[image]

I have the left arrow as image, but I don't know how to set it as a rounded back button image so I used a system image. Currently I have  this:

```
func configureNavigationBarButtons(){
let btnImage = UIImage(systemName: "arrow.left.circle.fill")

var buttonImage = btnImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
buttonImage = buttonImage?.withTintColor(UIColor.gray)

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.gray
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = buttonImage
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = buttonImage
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem?.backBarButtonItem?.image = buttonImage
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for:.default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layoutIfNeeded()
```

I don't know why, but the btnImage?.withRenderingMode didn't work so I had to set navigationBar.tintColor. In addition, I don't know why the image doesn't show up unless I set it to all 3 below:

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = buttonImage
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = buttonImage
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem?.backBarButtonItem?.image = buttonImage

Currently, I have the following as result, how can I achieve the result above? My left arrow image:

[image]
Thank you so much for your help.

[image]